# Homepage with "/" at the end

Tags: nginx, url, url-rewriting, request, trailing-slash

Let's say I have a site with URL: **example.com**
Does Google is treating "example.com" and "example.com/" pages as separate - So google thinks that one of them are duplicate?
If so, is it possible to configure 301 redirects from “example.com” to “example.com/” with a slash at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`example.com` is not an URL, it is a domain name, hostname, or website name depending on how you look at it.

An URL would be `http://example.com/`. You could write it as `http://example.com` if you want, but if you try in your browser you will see it gets rewritten immediately as `http://example.com/`.

Because when the browser connects to an HTTP server it sends a query like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

The thing after `GET` is the path, and it can not be empty. So it needs to be at least `/`, the root of the website.